# How to change the method within a class dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change the method `changeThis` dynamically by replacing the method with the value of an radio element. So if I select event1, the method needs to be changed to `Class.event1()`

```
<input 
       type="radio"
       class="radio-input"
       id="1"
       value="event1"
       ng-model="$ctrl.eventType"
       ng-change="$ctrl.updateEvent()" />
```

JS:

```
updateEvent() {
 const getEvent = Class.changeThis({
    title: 'Happy Time',
    location: 'New York, NY',
    description: 'Let\'s go!'
 });
}
```

I tried:

```
const getEvent = Class + '.'+ this.eventType({ 
     title: 'Happy Time',
     location: 'New York, NY',
     description: 'Let\'s go!'
  });
}
```

but get the error `eventType is not a function`. When I change it to a function it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? on click of event1, what value you had before and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

You can access objects property (or method) dynamically like this:

```
myObj["my" + "property"]
```

So, in your case it would be:

```
Class[this.eventType]({ ... });
```